# Historico de encomendas não funciona

Tags: joomla

Tenho um site de vendas online e quando o cliente faz uma encomenda automaticamente na conta dele é criado um historico com todas as encomendas feitas.

O problema é que quando ligo o `Friendly URL` e `URL Rewriting` o histórico deixa de funcionar e diz que a encomenda foi apagada ou movida.

Alguem sabe como resolver?

Obrigado, Aweb

Comment: poderia colocar o código para analisarmos o que foi feito?

Comment: Eu não alterei o codigo mas vou dar um exemplo do URL
Quando em URL Friendly
/historique-des-commandes/number/NB-FT/01-0010
Quando desligo URL Friendly
/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=orders&layout=details&order_number=NB-FT/01-0010&Itemid=513

Comment: Não mexo com Joomla, posso está falando besteira, mas sei que em outras frameworks ao ligar o `Friendly URL` você precisa alterar o `.htaccess`, você já alterou ?

Comment: Gilherme lopes agora que falas nisso do .htaccess me lembro de ter feito mudado algum codigo para o 'friendly url' funcionar, vou experimentar ver o 'htaccess' e ver se resolvo o problema